# Replace with html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace any text like this in input: `[www.Link-to-be-shortened.com]following link(cut)`

I want to replace it with `<a href="cuer.esy.es/?f=www.Link-to-be-shortened.com">following link</a>`by javascript

I have tried this code :

```
var UserString = " Hi <br>This article is good , Please visit the following link [www.Link-to-be-shortened.com]following link(cut)";
var SystemString = UserString.replace("[", "");
SystemString = SystemString.replace("]following link(cut)", "");
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("following link");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "following link";
a.href = "http://cuer.esy.es/?f="+SystemString;
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

But this code does not work well

Comment: Why dos not work well? any jsfiddle to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to do this with a regular expression:

```js
var UserString = "[www.Link-to-be-shortened.com]Click here(cut)";

var link = UserString.replace(/\[([^\[]+)\]([^(]+)\(cut\)/g, '<a href="cuer.esy.es/?f=$1">$2</a>');

console.log(link);
```

**HOWEVER**, this will not work in all possible cases. You could use this if only trusted people are submitting links.